# Grouping Objects In Array Based On Property Name

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array with a list of objects:

```
var myArray = [
    {"cartItems": {"paramA1": 25, "paramA2": 35}},
    {"cartShippingCost": {"paramB1": 4, "paramB2": 152, "paramB3": 536, "paramB4": 56}},
    {"cartSpecialRequirements": {"paramC1": 432}},
    {"cartPostage": {"paramD1": 56, "paramD2": 6537}},
    {"uid": {"paramE1": 545}},
    {"tel": 7778798548}
];
```

How can i loop through the above and group objects that contain `'cart'` and ones that don't?

I know i need to create 2 temp obj's e.g.

```
var cartObj;
var nonCartObj;
```

And perform a .push in to each of these if the condition is met.

Tried:

```
for(var i in myArray) { 
    if (i == 'cart') {
        console.log('cart match found');
    }
}
```

Update:

Using Object.keys always hitting else case:

```
var key = Object.keys(item);

if (key.indexOf("cart") !== -1) {
    alert(key + " contains cart");
} else {
    alert(key + " doesnt contain cart");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` to create a new array where each item satisfies some condition:

```
var cartItems = myArray.filter(hasCartProperty);
var nonCartItems = myArray.filter(function (x) { return !hasCartProperty(x); });


// Checks to see if any of the object's keys contain the text 'cart'
function hasCartProperty(x) {
    return Object.keys(x).some(function (x) {
        return x.indexOf('cart') > -1;
    });
}
```

Comment: @CalvinBelden - thanks, but isnt => only available in ES6. What about ES5?

Comment: Indeed, that was an interesting choice using it for one and not the other

Answer (score 2):

Loop through each item of the array, and then inside that loop iterate over the object keys to find what you're looking for

```
var result = [];
myArray.forEach(function (item) {
  for (var key in item) {
     if (key.indexOf('cart') !== -1) {
        result.push(item);
     }
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks, i made some progrss, and instead of your for loop, i used Object.keys... any pros or cons over each?

Comment: @OamPsy Object.keys is better because it won't iterate over properties like `toString`. I just opted to keep it simple. :)

Comment: ive added an update using Object.keys, but it always hits the else statement. Ill mark the above as the answer regardless, but any help on Object.keys would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript Array object has a [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) that can be used for this.

The tricky part is the function that performs the filtering. One way to do that is to iterate the keys in the objects to detect which ones contain "cart" keys.

```js
var myArray = [
    {"cartItems": {"paramA1": 25, "paramA2": 35}},
    {"cartShippingCost": {"paramB1": 4, "paramB2": 152, "paramB3": 536, "paramB4": 56}},
    {"cartSpecialRequirements": {"paramC1": 432}},
    {"cartPostage": {"paramD1": 56, "paramD2": 6537}},
    {"uid": {"paramE1": 545}},
    {"tel": 7778798548}
];

var cartObj = myArray.filter(function (x) { return isCart(x); });
var nonCartObj = myArray.filter(function (x) { return !isCart(x); });

console.log("cart count = " + cartObj.length + ", non-cart count = " + nonCartObj.length);

function isCart(x) {
  for (var key in x) {
    if (x.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.startsWith("cart")) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with one loop without `Array#filter()`.

```js
var myArray = [{ "cartItems": { "paramA1": 25, "paramA2": 35 } }, { "cartShippingCost": { "paramB1": 4, "paramB2": 152, "paramB3": 536, "paramB4": 56 } }, { "cartSpecialRequirements": { "paramC1": 432 } }, { "cartPostage": { "paramD1": 56, "paramD2": 6537 } }, { "uid": { "paramE1": 545 } }, { "tel": 7778798548 }],
    grouped = function (array) {
        var r = { cart: [], nonCart: [] };
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            Object.keys(a).some(function (k) {
                if (k.indexOf('cart') === 0) {
                    return r.cart.push(a);
                }
            }) || r.nonCart.push(a);
        });
        return r;
    }(myArray);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```